# ExternalInterface. addcallback works locally, but not on server?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

Confused by a problem with ExternalInterface.addcallback.

Mainly because I have it ALWAYS working locally, when I test in a browser, but the moment I deploy to a server it stops working.

I've added trace commands and confirmed that ExternalInterface is in fact available before adding the callback, and an alert command in the javascript method correctly identifies the flash object.
I also checked and allowscriptaccess is set to 'always'.

Could it have something to do with the flash being served on a remote server?

really stumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding System.security.allowDomain("*"); (or actually filling out the correct domain instead of *). To your AS.

You already have allowscriptaccess.  Also make sure the swf and the html/js are coming from the same host.... not www.foobar.com and foobar.com for the other, sometimes that will getcha.

Comment: Also try running it in a browser that has the debug flash plugin, you should see a security sandbox violation.